# SharePoint Modern Events Create and Details form

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

In SharePoint Communication site, can we customize the below form.

Create/Edit form
https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid=dc1227ed-540c-34c9-b767-2882641f5d6d&Mode=Edit

Details page
https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz/_layouts/15/Event.aspx?ListGuid=dc1227ed-540c-34c9-b767-2882641f5d6d

Answer (score 0):

The modern list form for Event list is not yet supported for customization (using PowerApps).

References:
[Modify Form in SharePoint Event List.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Modify-Form-in-SharePoint-Event-List/td-p/407733) /
(You can vote for the UserVoice post here:) [SharePoint Custom List Form: Event.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/SharePoint-Custom-List-Form-Event/idi-p/174029)

You can take a look at [developing a custom form as a web part using SPFx](https://366pi.tech/custom-sharepoint-form-using-spfx-no-javascript-framework/) if you are open for programmatic customization.